# how can i navigate to another page dynamically in phonegap

Tags: jquery, html, cordova

I have retrieved a data from the local database and displayed in a list using jquery,
but i want to know when i click on each item it should dynamically navigate to another view.

```
$('#Allwordslist').append('<li><a href="#"><h3 class="ui-li-heading">'+row['Word']+'</h3><p class="ui-li-desc">'+row['Type_Of_Word']+'</p></a></li>');
```

Comment: Nope.I'm developing on android mobile i.e android with phonegap

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jQuery mobile, you should look at [Dynamically injecting pages](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.1/docs/pages/page-dynamic.html). In brief, jQuery mobile handle page navigation by hijacking the click event on links. So, there are one obvious way for you to allow jQuery to handle your page navigation:

Put `<a href="page/to/go">` into your `li`. Then jQuery would navigate it for you. Of cause, the `page/to/go` should have been injected into `DOM`.

There is also another way to do that, jQuery mobile supply an API `$.mobile.changePage` to allow you navigate views.

```
function buildData(){
    //build *li*s based on your local data
    ...
    $('all lis').each(function(){
        $(this).click(function(){
            $.mobile.changePage(xxx, xxx);
        }
    });
}
```

In the [documentation](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.1/docs/pages/page-dynamic.html), there is also sample code show you how to inject pages dynamically, please read it carefully.

If you are using raw HTML pages, then you only need to use `<a href="next/page/you/go">`, instead of `<a href="#">`. So when you click this anchor, the `WebView` will load that page.

Comment: hi,thanks for the reply,but i'm newbie to jquery..i dont understand clearly..my question is when i click on entire row that is <li> it should navigate to another page in that i need to retrieve some  more data from database..can u please compare it to my code and let me know

Comment: What kind of **page** are you using? A traditional HTML page or just a pieces of HTML snippets? I used to use `div` to mock a page.

Comment: its completely a html page which includes jquery and java script..

Comment: still i'm unable to navigate it,in that code i'm just appending the data which i retrieved from then db..when i click on that each item then only it should navigate..pls let me know whr i'm mistaken