# Layout phonegap

Tags: javascript, android, html, cordova

I can't find how to set a layout with phone gap

Did the best way to navigate into the application is to user href in html or javascript ?

In this case I use html pages but I don't want to each time write the same head, header ...

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [jQueryMobile](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.1/docs/pages/page-dynamic.html) to navigate between pages efficiently.

Also, have a look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11700794/how-can-i-navigate-to-another-page-dynamically-in-phonegap) on StackOverflow.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm ever using JqueryMobile but the real question were how to have the same layout in all my pages

Comment: Same layout in all your pages ? I am sorry but I dont think I understand. You want the same layout in all your pages ?

Comment: Yes for exemple I have the same header code in each page and I don't want to rewrite my header in each pages (in the code)

Comment: You could use AJAX for that. Keep the header constant. And just redraw the frame that you want to update in your page. I haven't worked personally on this, but I am pretty much sure that it is possible.

Comment: Thanks I ever try it but this is not very clean, in this case if I click on the previous button on android the application is close and it didn't cames back to the last ajax call

Comment: Yes, that is because it is the same page and going back would mean closing the application. You need to override the backbutton to make it call the last AJAX function, instead of trying to going back to the previous page.